# $\lVert f \rVert _{H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^d )} \leq C \lVert f \rVert_{L^{1} (\mathbb{R}^d )}$ cannot hold at $ s= -d/2$.

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

How do I show that $\lVert f \rVert _{H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^d )} \leq C \lVert f \rVert_{L^{1} (\mathbb{R}^d )}$ cannot hold at $ s= -d/2$ ?

The definition is,

$\lVert f \rVert_{H^{s}} = \lVert \langle \nabla \rangle^{s}f \rVert_{L^2}$ and $\langle \nabla \rangle^{s} = (1+|\nabla|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}$.

I tried there is a $f$ which is not $H^{s}$ but is $L^1$.
I am gussing it is $\langle D \rangle ^{-s} \frac{1}{|x|^{d/2}}$. But I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea:** If you take $f(x) = \delta(x)$, then
you see that $\hat f(\xi) = \text{const}$, say $1$. Hence we have
\begin{align}
\|f\|_{H^{-d/2}(\mathbb{R}^d)} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{d\xi}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{d/2}} \sim \int^\infty_0\frac{r^{d-1}dr}{(1+r^d)} = \infty.
\end{align}
However, we see that $\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)} = 1.$ Thus the inequality fails for the delta function.

**Spoiler**:

> Let $d=1$. Take the sequence 
>  $f_N(x) = N(2\pi)^{-1/2}\exp(-N^2x^2/2)$

Comment: Can I ask why 'Spoiler' required ? I think the 'Idea' suffices to show.

Comment: Delta function is not a function.

Comment: Ooh, thank you.

Comment: Can I say $f:=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} f_{N}$ is a function? I think that function is what I want but I can't be sure because it approaches to Dirac delta function as I know.

Comment: Your job is to prove there does not exist a constant such that the inequality holds not whether $f_N$ converge to the delta function or not.